# Shazam was removed from the Microsoft Store; is there an alternative?

Tags: windows, music-recognition, shazam

To detect song titles I like to use the apps [Shazam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shazam.android) and [Musixmatch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.musixmatch.android.lyrify&rdid=com.musixmatch.android.lyrify) on my Android device. I read about Shazam existing for Windows also but it seems that it was removed from the Microsoft Store. Is there an alternative way to install it or an alternative application that does the same task so I do not have to use my Android device but can use Windows?

Comment: I am using **SoundHound**, you can search for Microsoft devices

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why looking for another app while this functionality is baked in into Cortana on Windows 10?

> 1. **Ask Cortana**
>      After launching, Cortana says “Ask me anything.” Simply ask her any
>      one of the following questions: What song is this?, What song is
>      playing?, What’s the name of this song?, or What’s playing right now?.
> 2. **Use Cortana’s Music Shortcut**
>      Alternatively, you can launch Cortana, then click the musical note
>      icon in the top right (similar to tapping the musical note icon that
>      appears in Google Now). Apart from identifying songs, this icon also
>      saves a list of your previous musical searches.

From (and see more) here: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/identify-song-cortana-windows-10/

Comment: This is an old topic but Cortana only works with selected languages, for example I use Hungarian localization/lang and I only have a basic search instead of full Cortana functionality. MS is a lazy company and they never made any advanced functionality available for people not speeking english, for example voice commands still aren't translated or at least made available on any lang even if it only takes englsih commands and it was introduced in W8 if I'm correct.

Comment: When I ask Cortana "What song is this?", it responds, "I'm sorry, I can't control your music here"

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Shazam has been discontinued,  as of Feb. 7, 2017,and no longer appears in the Microsoft App Store as an available download.
However the good news is that;

> Shazam will continue to work until or unless it becomes incompatible
>   with a different version of Microsoft’s operating system.

What you can do in the meantime is downloading the application from a different server:

1. [CDN Marketplace (direct-link)](http://disq.us/url?url=http%3A%2F%2Fcdn.marketplacecontent.windowsphone.com%2Fpublic%2F5089e8a0-d53c-4981-b885-93aa2d6ff37e%3Fdownloadname%3DShazam-4.7.8.0.appx%3ARxMlkZPBU-FBkqzIpYlWlDlcTvI&cuid=4014618) or
2. [Third-party hosted links](https://www.appx4fun.com/xap/918/)

You can then [side-load](https://www.howtogeek.com/285410/how-to-install-.appx-or-.appxbundle-software-on-windows-10/) manually on the Windows device either using the App Installer tool (Available in Windows 10’s Anniversary Update)

[image]

or using powershell:

i.e `Add-AppxPackage -Path "C:\Path\to\File.Appx"`

Comment: The package cannot be installed. It is for ARM architecture, not for x64. Tried with Powershell method and doubleclicking the package after enabling Sideload apps.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention the prerequisite, see [Packaging, deployment, and query of Windows store apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446767(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: The provided links only have the Windows Mobile versions of the app (which only run on ARM processors.) The "prerequisite" link you've provided doesn't give any way to install the ARM versions on x64.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a new project called FlairMax it's like Shazam but for Windows 10/Windows Mobile 10 and even with more features than Android version of Shazam check news on Twitter: @FlairMaxUWP https://twitter.com/FlairMaxUWP?s=09

FlairMax is a music recognition app that tell you the some information on the recognized track like: tittle, duration, genres, artist, release date, album, recognized part time (alpha, because it can mistake when the recognized part is repeated in the track), lyrics, synced lyrics (can be saved in many lyrics/subtitles formats), Deezer Link, YouTube Link, Spotify Link and Track HQ direct download link and there's another features like: show synced lyrics, Compact Overlay(PIP/AOS) mode, open track links in UWP apps/clients (MyTube, Perfect Tube, Spotify App, Deezer App, ....) if installed and many other features.

Comment: Welcome Ahmed! Please explain why your app is like Shazam and what additional features it has.  Thanks!

Comment: @RockPaperLizard FlairMax is a music recognition app that tell you the some information on track like: tittle, duration, genres, artist, release date, album, recognized part time (alpha, because it can mistake when the recognized part is repeated in the track), lyrics, synced lyrics (can be saved in many lyrics/subtitles formats), Deezer Link, YouTube Link, Spotify Link and Track HQ direct download link and there's another features like: show synced lyrics, Compact Overlay(PIP/AOS) mode, open track links in UWP apps/clients (MyTube, Perfect Tube, Spotify App, ....) if installed and many others

Comment: Thanks Ahmed! And my apologies, it would have been better if I mentioned that the content I requested needs to be added to your answer, not added as a comment.  If you have any trouble putting that helpful content into your answer, just let us know... we are here to help!

Comment: Can a link be provided @AhmedWalid?  All I could find was https://github.com/flairmax - or is it not yet available yet?

Comment: @Tom no, it's not available in the store yet but you can download the Appx(OLD I will update it) and the certificate files from Twitter BTW that GitHub Organization (that you mentioned) is mine I will upload some parts of the code on it because the app is not fully open source (68% from code is open source). Thanks!

Comment: @RockPaperLizard I added it to my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Please check SoundHound for Microsoft Windows Phones
You can find the store link here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/soundhound/9wzdncrfj3m2

You require to have one of the following OS running devices: Windows 10 Mobile, Windows Phone 8.1, Windows Phone 8